# HM-10 CC2541 Update Service Data 0xB000

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

This module usually sends in the adversiment data:

[image]

Is there a way to customize in Service Data with id B000 using arduino?

It usually sends this data format:

0x02, 0x16, 0x00, 0xB0 - [reserved], [temperature], [ humidity], [battery].

I wanna be able to update these service data and send custom data.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on a firmware change list of HM10:

> Add AT+FLAG[Para1] command    para1 value: 00~FF    Setup advertising
>   data flag
>
> Add AT+TEMP[P1] command to modify Temp flag byte in advertising data.
>   P1: 0x00~0xFF
>
> Add AT+HUMI[P1] command to modify Humi flag byte in advertising data.
>   P1: 0x00~0xFF
>
> Change AT+BATT[P1] command to query battery or modify Batt flag byte
>   in advertising data. P1: ? Query battery information P1: 0x00~0xFF(not
>   include '?') used to modify Batt flag byte in advertising data.

Answer (score 1):

Update HM-10 version up to V705, then you can use the new command AT+PACK to update service data.